# Como capturar o td de uma pagina web utilizando o selenium vba?

Tags: html, vba, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

o código html tem a seguinte aparência:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="01%" class="tex3b"><img height="14" src="/imagens/tm_bullet.gif" width="6"></td>
        <td width="20%" class="tex3b">Órgão</td>
        <td width="01%" class="tex3b">:</td>
```

A tag que eu quero selecionar:

```
        <td width="78%" class="tex3" colspan=4>22204&nbsp;-&nbsp;DEPARTAMENTO NAC.DE OBRAS CONTRA AS SECAS</td>
```

continuação da table:

```
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="01%" class="tex3b"><img height="14" src="/imagens/tm_bullet.gif" width="6"></td>
        <td width="20%" class="tex3b">UASG</td>
        <td width="01%" class="tex3b">:</td>
        <td width="78%" class="tex3" colspan=4>193003&nbsp;-&nbsp;DNOCS/CEST-CE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="01%" class="tex3b"><img height="14" src="/imagens/tm_bullet.gif" width="6"></td>
        <td width="20%" class="tex3b">Licitação</td>
        <td width="01%" class="tex3b">:</td>
        <td width="25%" class="tex3">PREGÃO</td>
        <td width="20%" class="tex3b" align=right>Número</td>
        <td width="01%" class="tex3b">:</td>
        <td width="32%" class="tex3">00002/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="01%" class="tex3b"><img height="14" src="/imagens/tm_bullet.gif" width="6"></td>
        <td width="20%" class="tex3b">Período de Vigência</td>
        <td width="01%" class="tex3b">:</td>
        <td width="25%" class="tex3b">18/12/2015 até 17/12/2016</td>
        <td width="20%" class="tex3b" align=right>Data Assinatura</td>
        <td width="01%" class="tex3b">:</td>
        <td width="32%" class="tex3">16/12/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=4><br></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

estou tentando capturar pelo Xpath mas nao tive muito sucesso, a variável fica vazia! Segue o codigo vba:

```
Set objCollection = driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]")
uasg = objCollection.getAttribute("Text") 'captura Uasg
```

Comment: votem na resposta se acharam útil rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui, o código ficou assim:

```
   Set objCollection = driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]")
   uasg = objCollection.Text 'captura Uasg
```